# Jquery logo parade not starting, not seeing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroller

I can't narrow down my problem with a simple logo parade.  I'm working on this at promasterautomotive.com so you can see the context of the problem.  The logo parade is at the very bottom, the faded logos.

I opened the console in Chrome (ctrl+shift+j) but I'm not seeing any errors.

Here is my javascript.  I pulled it directly from an example.

```
$(function() {
                $("#logoParade").smoothDivScroll({ 
                        autoScrollingMode: "always", 
                        autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight", 
                        autoScrollingStep: 1, 
                        autoScrollingInterval: 25 
                    });

                    // Logo parade event handlers
                    $("#logoParade").bind("mouseover", function() {
                        $(this).smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
                    }).bind("mouseout", function() {
                        $(this).smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
                    }); 
            });
```

Here's my HTML.  Again, modified from an example.  Once I get it working I'll tailor it as necessary.

```
<div id="logoParade">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/wiseco.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/bullydog.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/vortek.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" id="startAtMe"><img src="images/logos/sinister.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/schaeffers.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/arp.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/bpd.png" class="logos"></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/sct.png" class="logos"></a>
    </div>
```

Anyone else see something that I'm overlooking?

Comment: It should be `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is it doing instead? We can't help if we dont understnad the problem : )

Comment: @JeremyBlalock That's correct, but definitely not the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, guys.  I'm sorry, I should've specified.

What I'm going for is something like this...
http://smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several files on your site that the plugin depends on

This jsfiddle should work (looks like you moved or deleted the images though ...actually ..the whole site...)

http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/68sv070h/

Here are the requisite files (download your own copies of course);

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://smoothdivscroll.com/css/smoothDivScroll.css" />      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery.kinetic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://smoothdivscroll.com/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Note the following from the plugin's docs:**

LOAD JAVASCRIPT LATE - JUST BEFORE CLOSING THE BODY TAG. 
That way the browser will have loaded the images and will 
know the width of the images. No need to specify the width 
in the CSS or inline.

Comment: I must have a conflict of some sort because it's still not working.

Comment: You have not moved the file includes. Move the files mentioned above so that they are right before the `</body>` tag at the bottom of your html file

Comment: I did that, didn't work.  I see how that method would make this more effective once it was working, but I'm not getting any scrolling action.